# Is [Authorize] useless for internal service that behind the ocelot gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

Given that I have setup the ocelot and integrated with the IdentityServer4 according to the [ocelot document](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/authentication.html#jwt-tokens), should I remove the **`[Authorize]`** attribute and authentication related code (e.g. `UseAuthentication` middleware on `Startup`) from those internal services?

- if remove the `[Authorize]` and related code, how can those internal services get `User.Claims`? and how can those services be protected from threads coming from internal?
- if keep the `[Authroize]` and related code, then what's the point of integrate the IdentityServer4 with Ocelot? The only benefit I can see is prevent from the invalid requests arrive at the internal services.

---

**The long story:**

I setup the Ocelot gateway and integrate with the IdentityServer4. All my internal Api services (e.g. ServiceA, ServiceB) are behind the gateway.

To keep the internal services safe, I setup the `AuthenticationOptions` as the ocelot offical document said.

e.g. ocelot gateway configuration:

```js
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "LoadBalancerOptions": {
        "Type": "LeastConnection"
      },
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/serviceA/api/{version}/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "ApiGwAuth",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer("ApiGwAuth", x =>
        {
            x.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServiceSettings:Url"];
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudiences = new[] { "serviceA", "serviceB" }
            };
        });

    services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
}
```

serviceA which need to be proctected:

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetProtectedInfo()
{
     // e.g.     
     return Ok(User.Claims.Select(itm => itm.ToString()));
}
```

How to get the `User.Claims` if the `[Authorize]` and related code is removed?

Comment: is `this.User.Identity` empty?

Comment: @AndrewE Yes, User.Identity is empty.

Comment: have you tried adding an event to the `addJwtBeater` eg `options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents(){OnTokenValidated = async context =>{await Task.Yield();},` and confirming there is a jwt token there? if so you could create your own `this.User.Identity` also what about if you change the `[Authorize]` to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Answer (score 4):

If you remove UseAuthentication(), you will lose User.Identity.
If you want to generate User.Identity but without JWT validation that Ocelot passes, try following:

ConfigureServices

```
      services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = CreateTokenValidationParameters();
        });
```

Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

and

```
private TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters() //we ignore token validation because gateway validates it
    {
        var result = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
            {
                var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
                return jwt;
            },
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };
        result.RequireSignedTokens = false;
        return result;
    }
```